# My wireless has been set to “inactive”, how do I reactivate it?

Tags: macos, airport

I seem to have inadvertently deactivated my wireless in the "Network" section of System Preferences. When I go to the Airport icon in the menu bar it looks like a semicircle that, when clicked on, says "Airport: Not Configured". When I go to configure it, the status is shown as "Inactive", with no "Activate" button in sight. How can I get my wireless working again?
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The toggle to make a network adapter active/inactive is somewhat hidden. Select the AirPort adapter, then click the button that looks like a gear at the bottom of the list. This will open a dropdown and you can select "Make Service Active":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem with your connection to your network. Check that you're being properly authenticated, e.g. you have the correct WEP key, password.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with my wireless network as I can't even get to the point to select the network. I've added a screenshot to show what I mean.